# v-Select active selection

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify (Vue 2.0) and have the following component :
(https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/)

```
<v-select v-model="mail" :items="mails" dense clearable chips menu-props="auto"
label="..." v-on:change="..." prepend-icon="mdi-email-check">

<template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
    <v-chip small color="primary" text-color="white">{{data.item.dt_local}}</v-chip>
</template>

<template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
    <v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-icon>mdi-timeline-clock-outline</v-icon>
    </v-list-item-avatar>

    <v-list-item-content>
        <span v-if="(data.item.subject == null)">Aucun
            objet</span>
        <span v-else>{{ data.item.subject }}</span>
        <v-list-item-title>{{ data.item.dt_local }}
        </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
</template>

</v-select>
```

As a toy example :

```
this.mails = [
  {
    "subject": "Factures",
    "dt_local": "2022-12-03 09:54:48",
  },
  {
    "subject": "Factures",
    "dt_local": "2022-12-03 09:39:39",
  },
  {
    "subject": null,
    "dt_local": "2022-12-02 19:27:28",
  }
]
```

The problem i'm having is the following.
When i select any `item` i get the following output
[image]

The image above is obtained after i select the last element of the `v-select` component. (the one with `subject` = `null`).All items look `active`.
The expected output is as follows :[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `item-value` prop in order to work with the active select element.

You can do this like this-

```
<v-select 
   v-model="mail" 
   :items="mails" 
   dense 
   clearable 
   chips 
   item-value="dt_local"
   menu-props="auto"
   prepend-icon="mdi-email-check" 
   label="Select"
   return-object
>
 YOUR CODE HERE
</v-select>
```